# call gnu plot from c++ without user input

Tags: c++, gnuplot, popen

I found this code online. It makes a plot using gnuplot from data generated within c++. However it calls for user input and it doesn't work without the lines

```
      printf("press enter to continue...");        
      getchar();
```

The error message reads

```
     line 0: warning: Skipping unreadable file "tempData"
     line 0: No data in plot
```

Does anybody know a way around this? I want to use this code in a loop and not be called for input every time...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void plotResults(double* xData, double* yData, int dataSize);
int main() {
int i = 0;
int nIntervals = 100;
double intervalSize = 1.0;
double stepSize = intervalSize/nIntervals;
double* xData = (double*) malloc((nIntervals+1)*sizeof(double));
double* yData = (double*) malloc((nIntervals+1)*sizeof(double));
xData[0] = 0.0;
double x0 = 0.0;
for (i = 0; i < nIntervals; i++) {
    x0 = xData[i];
    xData[i+1] = x0 + stepSize;
}
for (i = 0; i <= nIntervals; i++) {
    x0 = xData[i];
  yData[i] = sin(x0)*cos(10*x0);
}
plotResults(xData,yData,nIntervals);
return 0;
}
void plotResults(double* xData, double* yData, int dataSize) {
FILE *gnuplotPipe,*tempDataFile;
char *tempDataFileName;
double x,y;
int i;
tempDataFileName = "tempData";
gnuplotPipe = popen("gnuplot","w");
if (gnuplotPipe) {
  fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"plot \"%s\" with lines\n",tempDataFileName);
  fflush(gnuplotPipe);
  tempDataFile = fopen(tempDataFileName,"w");
  for (i=0; i <= dataSize; i++) {
      x = xData[i];
      y = yData[i];            
          fprintf(tempDataFile,"%lf %lf\n",x,y);        
      }        
      fclose(tempDataFile);        
      printf("press enter to continue...");        
      getchar();        
      remove(tempDataFileName);        
      fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"exit \n"); 
      pclose(gnuplotPipe);   
  } else {        
      printf("gnuplot not found...");    
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to delete the line `remove(tempDataFileName)`

Comment: Thanks! that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual problem is that you removed the temp file to early. I would have restructured the code to:

```
if (gnuplotPipe) 
{
    // Create the temp file
    tempDataFile = fopen(tempDataFileName,"w");
    for (i=0; i <= dataSize; i++) 
    {
        x = xData[i];
        y = yData[i];            
        fprintf(tempDataFile,"%lf %lf\n",x,y);        
    }        
    fclose(tempDataFile);  

    // Send it to gnuplot
    fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"plot \"%s\" with lines\n",tempDataFileName);
    fflush(gnuplotPipe);
    fprintf(gnuplotPipe,"exit \n"); 
    pclose(gnuplotPipe); 

    // Clean up the temp file  
    remove(tempDataFileName);        
}
```

Then you will not end up with a lot of temp files on your system.

Another nice thing to do is to make gnuplot persistent so you are able to see the plot after the pipe is closed, simply add a `-p` flag when you open the pipe

`gnuplotPipe = popen("gnuplot -p","w");`